# How to Delete All previously tracked data in Google Mobile iOS App Analytics without changing the tracking id

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-analytics, analytics

Iam using Google Analytics SDK for iOS v3.0.9 in my app and tracked all the data during my development. Now the app is yet to be submitted in "Apps Store", so i need to delete all the previous data and track only the data after my app is released.

I need to use the same Tracking ID and the account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete it. That is why it is important to setup a test profile to send data to while you implement/qa. need ref use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419074/how-to-delete-a-event-from-event-tracking-of-google-analytics)

in my choice need to create the new GA account and submit to App Store

Comment: i used GA in last 3 projects ,in testing time i used some different a/c and when submitted to app store add the original ID, but your question is good one,